# Jquery, sorting & grouping for alphanumeric values

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a list of items which has alphabetic & numeric both type of values. 
I need to sort them like Alphabets sorted then number sorted. For eg : Apple Car 23 45
I am able to sort them using :

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.sortList = function() {
        debugger;
    var mylist = $(this);
    var listitems = $('a', mylist).get();
    listitems.sort(function(x, y) {
        if (isNaN(x.text) && isNaN(y.text)) {
            var compA = $(x).text().toUpperCase();
            var compB = $(y).text().toUpperCase();
            return (compA < compB) ? -1 : 1;
        } else {
            return (x.text < y.text) ? -1 : 1;}
        }
    );
    $.each(listitems, function(i, itm) {
        mylist.append(itm);
    });
   }    
});

//Call this function to sort the list
$("div#countries").sortList();
```

But using this, number are coming on top sometimes sorted, sometimes unsorted(Not sure why), & alphabets sorted perfectly after numbers.
I tried searching many forums for sorting & grouping altogether, but in jquery I am not able to do it.(I miss C# LinQ) :| Please help.

**EDIT 1 :**

As per below suggestion, I am using this code but my numeric values are also coming in the form of string, that is the reason digits are not getting sorted out.

Code :

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.sortList = function() {
        debugger;
    var mylist = $(this);
    var listitems = $('a', mylist).get();
    listitems.sort(function(x, y) {
        if($.isNumeric(x.text)){
            x.text = parseInt(x.text);
        }
        if($.isNumeric(y.text)){
            y.text = parseInt(y.text);
        }

        var a = Number(x.text);
        var b = Number(y.text);
        if (isNaN(a)) {
                    if (isNaN(b)) {
                        var compA = x.text.toUpperCase();
                        var compB = y.text.toUpperCase();
                        return (compA < compB) ? -1 : 1;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                } 
        else{
                    if (isNaN(b)) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return a - b;
                }
            }
        });

    $.each(listitems, function(i, itm) {
        mylist.append(itm);
    });
   }    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `isNaN` expects a number while you provide a string.
Also, you are not treating the case where `x` is a number and `y` is a string, or vice versa.

You should use this comparator:

```
function compare(x, y) {
    var a = Number(x.text);
    var b = Number(y.text);
    if (isNaN(a)) {
        if (isNaN(b)) {
            var compA = x.text.toUpperCase();
            var compB = y.text.toUpperCase();
            return (compA < compB) ? -1 : 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        if (isNaN(b)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just find out after lot of debugging that it is still not sorting digits because they are coming with ''(in form of string) :| any help?

Comment: I am editing my question for my updated code, as per your suggestion & the issue I find out.

Comment: Can you give an example (for example jsfiddle or something similar) where it does not work?